# PHP AJAX File Uploader

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Does anyone know of a good **PHP** based file uploader using AJAX?

The demo below look promising, but it's for ASP.Net

http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=ASP.NET+File+Upload+with+*Real-Time*+Progress+Bar&Filter=All

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to write as much code my self as I can, here is a great tutorial with working examples using the jQuery library: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: This webpage is not available

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with this one:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: Yes, me too, which is why I've helped form version 2.0 which is now here: http://valums-file-uploader.github.com/file-uploader/

Comment: @Simon - It does not have instruction of how to use it. For example , the file "/client/demo.htm" - says "click on the button below" but does not contain any button, and the drop areas does not accept files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look [at ibm example.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v525/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice ajax file uploader:

http://www.ajaxf1.com/product/ajax-file-upload.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy and good one file upploader , which can give power  for upload many files from one form in async fashion. we have used in our application and working (running) fine. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/jquery_file_upload.php?print=Y

It also contains documentation which help you to edit it.